# CentOS 7 on Amazon ec2 hangs on reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 server on Amazon ec2, I'm using the AMI from CentOS.

It takes about 10min to restart the server,

I got this line from the messages log:

> Nov 19 14:26:35 XXXXX systemd: Startup finished in 2.034s (kernel) + 10.576s (initrd) + 12.801s (userspace) = 25.413s.

It shows me that there are no hangups in the boot process.

This is rsyslog from messages log:

> Nov 19 14:16:14 XXXXX rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="560" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
>   Nov 19 14:26:28 XXXXX rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="560" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

And it shows that it takes 10min from rsyslog shuts down until it starts again.

What could be making the reboot hang?

**Update**, I tried to do a reboot again from the EC2 Management Console.
Looking at the system log in the EC2 Management Console it took 5 minutes to go from,

> [429844.962972] reboot: machine restart

to the next update.

> [H[J[1;1H[?25l[m[H[J[1;1H[20;7H[mUse the ^ and v keys to change the selection.
>   Press 'e' to edit the selected item, or 'c' for a command prompt.   [4;80H [7m[4;1H      CentOS Linux (3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)

Which looks like the first line of the GRUB boot menu.

It seems like CentOS isn't rebooting the machine at the end, and Amazon waits 4-5 minutes then hard resets the machine.
[Amazon Reboot process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html)

Comment: could it be linked to some dns bad resolution ? something timing out ? Anything network related ?

Comment: @pat I added some more log info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is actually rebooting fine but is waiting for you to select from the grub menu. When you don't select it after a while it will time out and boot up on whatever the first selection is. Open your grub config and set

`GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0`

then reload grub. That will hopefully take care of it for you.

Comment: The GRUB_TIMEOUT is set to 1 sec, so that would not account for the missing 4 minutes.